# Google App Engine - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib'

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask, gunicorn, dlib

I have a Flask application that uses the 'dlib' library. I am trying to run it on Google App Engine but it fails as soon as I try to access it. Error in the log is 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib''. Previously, I had 'dlib' in the requirements.txt file but while deploying the application it always failed with an error related to 'CMAKE'. Then I manually installed 'dlib' through the Google console. Currently it is under "Location:/home/*myusername*/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages".

When I am trying to run the application locally on Google console it works perfectly fine but with `gcloud app deploy` command it is not working. I have wasted 2 days trying to figure out the problem without any success. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you using App Engine Flex or standard?

Comment: @YeriPelona flex environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look into this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63897818/workaround-to-install-cmake-on-gcp-app-engine-standard-environment).

Summarazing:

- You can use non-Python dependencies in the Flexible environment, via a [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes):

> Custom runtimes allow you to define new runtime environments, which might include additional components like language interpreters or application servers.

- If you want to customize your environment, you can use a container. There are some considerations that would be good to keep in mind:
- Flex doesn't scale to 0, and thus you pay even if your service isn't used.
- In such case, a workaround could be [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run). It can scale to zero and its payed per use, additionally that is powerful.